# Getting error when plotting a figure with sublpots using axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I tried to plot the subplots using the below code .But I am getting `'AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'boxplot'`.

but changing the `plt.subplots(1,2)` it is plotting the box plot with indexerror.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(10,5))

x = [i for i in range(100)]


fig , axes = plt.subplots(2,2)

for i in range(4):
    sns.boxplot(x, ax=axes[i])

plt.show();
```

I am expecting four subplots should be plotted but AttributeError is throwing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues in your plot:

- You are defining the figure twice which is not needed. I merged them into one.
- You were looping 4 times using `range(4)` and using `axes[i]` for accessing the subplots. This is wrong for the following reason: Your axes is 2 dimensional so you need 2 indices to access it. Each dimension has length 2 because you have 2 rows and 2 columns so the only indices you can use are 0 and 1 along each axis. For ex. `axes[0,1]`, `axes[1,0]` etc.
- As @DavidG pointed out, you don't need the list comprehension. YOu can directly use `range(100)`

The solution is to expand/flatten make your 2d axes object and then directly iterate over it which gives you individual subplot, one at a time. The order of subplots will be row wise.

---

**Complete working code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = range(100)

fig , axes = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(10,5))

for ax_ in axes.flatten():
    sns.boxplot(x, ax=ax_)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could even remove the list comprehension as that isn't really needed either?